# Swift doesn't return the correct value in recursive function

Tags: ios, swift, recursion, backtracking, sudoku

I tried to implement backtracking solution for a sudoku solver in swift. This is my code:

```
func solve(board: [[Int]]) -> (isSolved: Bool, board: [[Int]]){
    var board = board
    var empty_pos: (Int, Int)
    var check_empty = findEmpty(board: board)

    if check_empty.isEmpty == false{
        return (true, board)
    }else{
        empty_pos = check_empty.pos

        for num in 1..<10{
            if isValid(board: board, num: num, pos: empty_pos){

                board[empty_pos.0][empty_pos.1] = num

                if solve(board: board).isSolved{
                    return (true, board)
                }else{
                    board[empty_pos.0][empty_pos.1] = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return (false, board)}
```

When I run the code, the function returns true with the original board. However, when I print the board in the if solved block, I noticed that function solves the board, but it doesn't return it, and continues to call the function until it makes all of the 0 values 0 again. I think the function doesn't quit in the if solve(board: board).isSolved part. What should I do to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend you make a `SudokuBoard` struct to abstract over the `[[Int]]`. Then you could just make a `solve` method on it that returns `SudokuBoard?`, either `nil` (no solution), or a solved board.

Comment: I would also recommend against using recursion in cases that are easily done by looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are not returning the modified return value from `solve`, but just discarding it and returning the local variable `board`.

You should be saving the return value from the recursive call and if its `isSolved` property is true, return the `board` from the recursive call, not the local var.

```
func solve(board: [[Int]]) -> (isSolved: Bool, board: [[Int]]) {
    var board = board
    var emptyPos: (Int, Int)
    var checkEmpty = findEmpty(board: board)

    if !checkEmpty.isEmpty {
        return (true, board)
    } else {
        emptyPos = checkEmpty.pos

        for num in 1..<10 {
            if isValid(board: board, num: num, pos: emptyPos){

                board[emptyPos.0][emptyPos.1] = num

                let solved = solve(board: board)
                if solved.isSolved {
                    return (true, solved.board)
                } else{
                    board[emptyPos.0][emptyPos.1] = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return (false, board)
}
```

Unrelated to your question, but you should be conforming to the Swift naming convention, which is lowerCamelCase for variable and function names.